# Moody ability and how to obtain?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Is the Moody [hidden] ability still in X & Y? If so, how is it obtained (say for Bidoof)?

I've done some research that it was obtained via Dream Points in B&W (I never played them), so I'm at a loss for X & Y.

Comment: It is still available in X/Y, but not sure how it is obtained. Hidden abilities didn't go away, but how to get them may have changed.

Comment: Note that X and Y released the same time here as in Japan. Reverting your edit suggesting otherwise as it just clutters the question.

Comment: @dlras2 Oops thanks! Thought JP had released earlier.

Comment: @Zeno It has for every other game, I believe. This is the first simultaneous world-wide release, which is why it's so hard to find any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing more research, I've heard that these are generally obtained in the Friend Safari. If anyone can confirm, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Hidden abilities are also found in hordes, but as Bidoof/Bibarel do not seem to occur in hordes...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Moody hidden ability is in gen VI. To obtain it, you would first need a friend safari in which the Pokemon with Moody can be found. The list of pokemon with Moody that can be found in the friend safari is as follows:

- Smeargle (Normal)
- Octillery (Water)
- Bibarel (Water)
- Snorunt (Ice)

To cause pokemon in a given friend safari to have their hidden ability (in this case Moody), you also need to be online at the same time as the friend you obtained the safari from.

Source: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friend_Safari

P.S. You could also import one from gen V via Poke Transporter, but that probably isn't what you meant.